# Probability of three players rolling a single die; where rolling a six is a loss

Tags: probability

Afternoon all; I'm following along with [Harvard's Extension school class: "Sets, Counting, and Probability"](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/sets-counting-probability) and am stuck on a particular question:

[image: Elementary Probability 2nd ed. - Stirzaker]
[image: Elementary Probability 2nd ed. - Stirzaker]

I've been able to (after much work), get the correct answer for the question:

"Show that the probability that Achilles is last to throw a six is 305/1001" by way of

```
P(r) = 1/6 * [(5/6)^r * (1 - (5/6)^r)^2]
```

and then calculating the geometric sum between the broken down components; multiplying their total aggregate by 1/6.

However, for the question, "For each player, find the probability that he or she is the first to roll a six." I've tried pages and pages of what I think may be correct, but just cannot figure out how the answers provided in the index were attained.

I've tried attacking the problem the same way as above, by letting

```
P(r) = 1/6 * [ (5/6)^3r ]
```

Which to me seems the correct route for P(A) - the intersection of each A, B, and C having rolled all {1,2...5} to this point, where P(r) is the probability of the event where A rolls a six first.

The related lecture discussion can be found at 1h39m at [the Lecture recording](http://oli.extension.harvard.edu/mathe102/2003/fall/lectures/math-e102-L02-20050927.flv)

Answers from Index

- P(A): 36/91
- P(B): 30/91
- P(C): 25/91

I would really appreciate any ideas!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to find the individual probabilities is to think of it in terms of adding disjoint events whose union is that probability in question. So for the person in the $i$th of ABC (e.g. Brises is in the 2nd position), we can add up all of the ways that person in $i$th position can roll a six first. This essentially means he could roll a six first on first set of rolls, or second set of rolls, and so on. Now we notice that the probability that the person in the $i$th position wins on the $n$th set of rolls is equal to
$$\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{(i-1)+3(n-1)}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$$
Why is this? This is because if you have the $i$th turn and you want to roll to roll six first on $n$th turn you need $(i-1)+3(n-1)$ (*) positions  before you to fail and than you to win. Thus we have
$$P\left(\textrm{Person in position i rolls 6 first}\right)=P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\textrm{Person in in positon i rolls 6 first on turn n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(\textrm{Person in in positon i rolls 6 first on turn n}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{(i-1)+3(n-1)}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{(i-1)+3n}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{i-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\right)\left(\frac{5^{3}}{6^{3}}\right)^{n}$$
where this is a geometric series thus we have
$$=\frac{\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{i-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}{1-\frac{5^{3}}{6^{3}}}=\frac{(6^{3-i})(5^{i-1})}{91}$$

And for here we have A($i=1$), B ($i=2$), and C ($i=3$)

(*) to derive this $(i-1)+3(n-1)$ you have to think of how many failures do you have before person in $i$th position rolls six first in $n$th set of rolls. Well first you will need $n-1$ set of rolls all to be failures in order to have success on $n$th set, so that is $3(n-1)$ failures. Then you need the people in the positions before person in $i$th position, i.e. $i-1$ positions, to fail also. So in total you need $(i-1)+3(n-1)$ positions to not roll a six before person in $i$th position does so on $n$th set of rolls

Comment: Awesome, I finally had a chance to take a look at this in depth and solve it for myself. This explanation works well, but it also highlighted a gap in my understanding of the [Geometric Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). I thought the Professor had explained it thoroughly, but it seems that as `|5/6^3n| < 1` then the formula is that of `a / r`, where a is the 'fixed' parts of `(5/6)^i-1 * (1/6)` and r is the series part of `(5/6)^3n`. Which explains the last step. I ended up with `( (6^2) * (5/6)^i-1 ) / 91 ` which is correct. Can you explain the (6^(3-i)*5^(i-1))/91 ?

Comment: those two expressions are equivalent just use properties of exponents

Answer (score 4):

We give a series-free solution to your last problem by conditioning on the results of the first three throws.

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ respectively be the probability that A, B, C is the first to roll a $6$.

Maybe A gets a $6$ immediately. Or maybe A fails on the first roll. Then the probability A is gets the first $6$ is $c$, because now in effect A is third.

Thus
$$a=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}c\tag{1}$$

Maybe A fails on her first trial. Then either B rolls a $6$, or she is in effect third. Thus
$$b=\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}c.\tag{2}$$

A similar analysis shows that 
$$c=\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}c.\tag{3}$$

Equation (3) immediately yields $c=\frac{25}{91}$. Equations (1) and (2) now tell us what $a$ and $b$ are.

Comment: never cease to amaze me by the simple proofs you give, so much easier than what I had done

Comment: Both were great answers, but I had to choose @user159813 's because of the equations laid out in a way I can understand and learn from.

Comment: That is exactly what you are asked to do, choose the answer that is most helpful.